# How to change the entire color of the selected stack bar on a click event in highchart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using a combination of stack bar and line chart at the same with the help of HighChart, I want to be able to select a bar(or in my case the entire stack bar as well as the point in the line graph) and change its color when I click on it,

Right now I am able to select a bar and change its color but not able to change the color of both bars and the point of the line which was clicked

Below is the click of the code which I tried from my end, I want to be able to select the entire bar and line when clicked, but I am only able to select one of them

[SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shockley-tko2o6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your SanBox Link doesn't work correctly. Do you want to achieve something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hx059wp3/

Answer (score -1):

I tried this sorry that the sandbox link was broken

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {


  "chart": {
    "zoomType": "xy",
    "height": 320
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "align": "left",
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Poppins, Helvetica, \"sans-serif\"",
      "fontWeight": "600"
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "categories": [
      "0.01-0.05",
      "0.06-0.10",
      "0.11-0.15",
      "0.16-0.20",
      "0.21-0.25",
      "0.26-0.30",
      "0.31-0.35",
      "0.36-0.40",
      "0.41-0.45",
      "0.46-0.50",
      "0.51-0.55",
      "0.56-0.60",
      "0.61-0.65",
      "0.66-0.70",
      "0.71-0.75",
      "0.76-0.80",
      "0.81-0.85",
      "0.86-0.90",
      "0.91-0.95",
      "0.96-1.00"
    ],
    "crosshair": true,
    "plotLines": [{
      "color": "#A9A9A9",
      "width": 3,
      "value": 9.5,
      "dashStyle": "longdashdot"
    }]
  },
  "yAxis": [{
      "title": {
        "text": "Count"
      },
      "min": 0
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "text": "y1 count"
      },
      "opposite": true,
      "min": 0
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      point: {
        events: {
          click() {
             var indexP = this.x,
            series = this.series.chart.series;

        if (series[0].data[indexP].selected) {
            //unselect
            series[0].data[indexP].select(false, true);
            series[1].data[indexP].select(false, true);

        } else {
            var i = 0;
            var len = series[1].data.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { //clear all selection
                series[0].data[i].select(false, true);
                series[1].data[i].select(false, true);
                series[2].data[i].select(false, true);
            }
            //select
            series[0].data[indexP].select(true, true);
            series[1].data[indexP].select(true, true);
            series[2].data[indexP].select(true, true);
        }

        return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "legend": {
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "top"
  },
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
      "name": "y1",
      "type": "column",
      "stack": 1,
      "yAxis": 1,
      "color": "rgb(217, 141, 39)",
      "data": [
        1,
        13,
        24,
        25,
        34,
        74,
        104,
        66,
        104,
        121,
        111,
        89,
        87,
        97,
        93,
        92,
        100,
        147,
        250,
        567
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": " "
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "y3",
      "type": "column",
      "stack": 1,
      "yAxis": 1,
      "color": "rgb(44, 99, 143)",
      "data": [
        463,
        287,
        208,
        201,
        209,
        197,
        171,
        150,
        134,
        102,
        65,
        50,
        36,
        24,
        33,
        20,
        13,
        13,
        10,
        9
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "y3",
      "type": "line",
      "color": "#F1416C",
      "data": [
        1,
        14,
        38,
        63,
        97,
        171,
        275,
        341,
        445,
        566,
        677,
        766,
        853,
        950,
        1043,
        1135,
        1235,
        1382,
        1632,
        2199
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": " "
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```