# How to get the value of x-axis of a column graph when user click on the hover area when the points are to small to click in high-chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, highcharts

The question is related to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998884/how-to-change-the-entire-color-of-the-selected-stack-bar-on-a-click-event-in-hig/73070736#73070736)

I have a stacked column chart where I have multiple bars which can have different values, I want to alert the value of the bar clicked and at the same time change the color. I was able to get the value of the selected stacked bar and change its color but run into a problem

Although the current implementation is fine there is an issue when it comes to the small data set the bar is not clickable, So I was wondering if there is a way where I can select a bar on its hover area, as when we hover over the bar there is an animation of hover when we move from one bar to another

So just to reiterate I want to be able to select the bar when I click on its hover area

Below is my current implementation

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {


  "chart": {
    "zoomType": "xy",
    "height": 320
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "align": "left",
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Poppins, Helvetica, \"sans-serif\"",
      "fontWeight": "600"
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "categories": [
      "0.01-0.05",
      "0.06-0.10",
      "0.11-0.15",
      "0.16-0.20",
      "0.21-0.25",
      "0.26-0.30",
      "0.31-0.35",
      "0.36-0.40",
      "0.41-0.45",
      "0.46-0.50",
      "0.51-0.55",
      "0.56-0.60",
      "0.61-0.65",
      "0.66-0.70",
      "0.71-0.75",
      "0.76-0.80",
      "0.81-0.85",
      "0.86-0.90",
      "0.91-0.95",
      "0.96-1.00"
    ],
    "crosshair": true,
    "plotLines": [{
      "color": "#A9A9A9",
      "width": 3,
      "value": 9.5,
      "dashStyle": "longdashdot"
    }]
  },
  "yAxis": [{
      "title": {
        "text": "Count"
      },
      "min": 0
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "text": "y1 count"
      },
      "opposite": true,
      "min": 0
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      point: {
        events: {
          click() {
             var indexP = this.x,
            series = this.series.chart.series;

        if (series[0].data[indexP].selected) {
            //unselect
            series[0].data[indexP].select(false, true);
            series[1].data[indexP].select(false, true);

        } else {
            var i = 0;
            var len = series[1].data.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { //clear all selection
                series[0].data[i].select(false, true);
                series[1].data[i].select(false, true);
                series[2].data[i].select(false, true);
            }
            //select
            series[0].data[indexP].select(true, true);
            series[1].data[indexP].select(true, true);
            series[2].data[indexP].select(true, true);
        }

        return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "legend": {
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "top"
  },
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
      "name": "y1",
      "type": "column",
      "stack": 1,
      "yAxis": 1,
      "color": "rgb(217, 141, 39)",
      "data": [
        1,
        13,
        24,
        25,
        34,
        74,
        104,
        66,
        104,
        121,
        111,
        89,
        87,
        97,
        93,
        92,
        100,
        147,
        250,
        567
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": " "
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "y3",
      "type": "column",
      "stack": 1,
      "yAxis": 1,
      "color": "rgb(44, 99, 143)",
      "data": [
        463,
        287,
        208,
        201,
        209,
        197,
        171,
        150,
        134,
        102,
        65,
        50,
        36,
        24,
        33,
        20,
        13,
        13,
        10,
        9
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "y3",
      "type": "line",
      "color": "#F1416C",
      "data": [
        1,
        14,
        38,
        63,
        97,
        171,
        275,
        341,
        445,
        566,
        677,
        766,
        853,
        950,
        1043,
        1135,
        1235,
        1382,
        1632,
        2199
      ],
      "tooltip": {
        "valueSuffix": " "
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Hope I was able to explain my query better

Comment: Hi, in your earlier post a solution was presented, isn't that what you meant?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Actually, in the previous Solution, the bar color changes when you click on the bar itself, but here I want to be able to click on the hover area of a particle bar and then change its color I hope I answered your concern?

Comment: You have more events that you can use when entering to the point area, like [point.events.mouseOut](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.point.events.mouseOut) and [point.events.mouseOver](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.point.events.mouseOver). Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hx059wp3/1/

Comment: This works altho once you select the colors to change for all bars after selection, the shouldn't the previous bar go back to their original color @SebastianHajdus

Comment: Does original color mean you mean the color of the series?  I'm a little confused as to what you want to achieve, hopefully with this example and maybe using other events on the point you will be able to achieve your goal.